# Finding the number of leading zeros from numbers in a vector

Tags: matlab, vector, statistics

I have a vector. Let say x=[0 -2 -1 -1 -1 0 0 -1]. I want to find symbols from x vector. Symbols are (1,-2), (0,-1), (0,-1), (0,-1), (2,-1).

(1,-2) means that there is one "0" in front of "-2".
(0,-1) means that there is no "0" in front of "-1".
(2,-1) means that there are two "0" in front of "-1".

Any idea? It seems a bit hard to code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `find` and `diff`:

```
x=[0 -2 -1 -1 -1 0 0 -1];

idx = find(x ~= 0); % Get the positions of the non-zero elements
symbols = [diff([0,idx])-1; x(idx)]; % Number of positions since previous non-zero
                                     % With the corresponding element underneath
```

To get the output

```
symbols =
     1     0     0     0     2
    -2    -1    -1    -1    -1
```

Where your pairs correspond to the columns in this array.

Comment: Wolfie, thanks for the answer. I have many many symbols like that.Think that there is a "NX1 cell" that has "2xM double" in every row. M may be differ in every row. I have to find the probability of each symbol and it is hard to calculate from this type of representation.  Is there a way to show the symbols such as I mentioned in the question?

Comment: MATLAB is built to be good at handling matrices, you'll struggle to represent the symbols in any more efficient way than this... You could make a cell array of 2x1 vectors which might look more like your question representation but it will be much harder to work with for any computations... If you're stuck on something related but new, please just ask a new question